# No. 5: What's the next element in this sequence?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Part of a series of similar puzzles - the answer to one will give you the type of thinking required for the others. The difficulty of these challenges will now start to increase.

**What's the next element in this series? What's the relationship?**

```
- ~
3 0
1 2
0 1
1 1
4 0
3 0
1 1 (dispution level: high)
3 0
3 0 (dispution level: low)
1 1 (dispution level: medium)
3 0
2 0
4 0
3 0
0 1
1 1
1 1
2 1
0 1
2 0
0 1
2 0
4 0
2 0
3 0 (dispution level: medium)
```

While I will keep the `knowledge` tag to be consistent with the others in this series, note that this particular challenge I can guarrantee that every one has the required knowledge to solve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next element is

> Z (3 0)

The series represents

> How many straight and curved strokes you need to write all uppercase letters in the Latin alphabet, in order: for example, A needs 3 straight lines and no curved lines. Z, the last element, would need 3 straight lines.